# Regular expression for street address?

Tags: regex

i need regular expression for street address for example:

```
test 123 - valid
123 test -not valid
```

So i need letters(required) then space and then number(required)
I tried this but without success

```
@"^[A-Za-z ][0-9 ]"
```

Comment: where are the `quantifiers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the quantifiers, anchors.

```
@"^[A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+$"
```

`+` repeats the previous token one or more times.

You may use this if the space is optional.

```
@"^[A-Za-z]+ ?[0-9]+$"
```

Comment: Thats it..tnx..i cant accept your question for 5 more minutes...but i will :)